# How to handle HTML `select` multiple value in Node back end if only one option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an HTML `select` element with the `multiple` attribute where users can select one or more options, sending to a Node back end through body-parser.

If the user selects more than one option, body-parser turns it into an array. However if the user only selects one option, it just sends a string of the one `option`'s value.

I have a loop to process each selected value, but when only the string is sent, it tries to loop over each individual character.

I'd rather not have to check `typeof` req.body.selectElement and have essentially the same logic for a single string, or each string element of an array. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: The js `isArray()` method determines whether an object is an array. 

This function returns true if the object is an array, and false if not.

Comment: Right, but do I *have* to see whether the output is an array, and then do the same things either with just the string, or with each array element? Or is there a way to force the output to be an array, even with a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's convention for named fields ending with square brackets `[]` to be treated as arrays, so I would try adding `[]` to the end of the `name` field of your `select` element.

For example:

```
<select name="data[]" multiple>
  <option value="option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! If this hadn't been available, I had a 'hacky' solution to force the output into an array: 
    ```if (typeof req.body.chooseAdmins === 'string') {
      req.body.chooseAdmins = [req.body.chooseAdmins]
    };```